# Crash when swiping a view multiple times in iOS using Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having a rather odd crash on my app for iOS using Titanium 3.2.1 running on iOS7. I get the error on both simulator and device.

This is the stack trace.....

```
[INFO] :   2014-02-21 22:01:20.378 2000 Words[78335:80b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
[INFO] :   *** First throw call stack:
[INFO] :   (
[INFO] :    0   CoreFoundation                      0x042215e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
[INFO] :    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03ee18b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
[INFO] :    2   CoreFoundation                      0x041c24e6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
[INFO] :    3   2000 Words                          0x0007b800 -[TiViewProxy insertSubview:forProxy:] + 1520
[INFO] :    4   2000 Words                          0x0007c07b -[TiViewProxy relayout] + 2075
[INFO] :    5   2000 Words                          0x0007ab23 -[TiViewProxy refreshView:] + 675
[INFO] :    6   2000 Words                          0x0007c393 -[TiViewProxy layoutChildrenIfNeeded] + 259
[INFO] :    7   2000 Words                          0x00204397 +[TiLayoutQueue layoutProxy:] + 87
[INFO] :    8   2000 Words                          0x00204162 performLayoutRefresh + 530
[INFO] :    9   CoreFoundation                      0x041dfbd6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
[INFO] :    10  CoreFoundation                      0x041df5bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
[INFO] :    11  CoreFoundation                      0x041c7628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
[INFO] :    12  CoreFoundation                      0x041c6ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
[INFO] :    13  CoreFoundation                      0x041c68db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
[INFO] :    14  GraphicsServices                    0x046769e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
[INFO] :    15  GraphicsServices                    0x04676809 GSEventRun + 104
[INFO] :    16  UIKit                               0x01542d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
[INFO] :    17  2000 Words                          0x00003738 main + 456
[INFO] :    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x0500c70d start + 1
[INFO] :   )
[INFO] :   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The crash happens when you swipe one of my views (the view is called 'back'), around 3 or 4 times. Without fail it throws an error.

Basically, the 'back' view displays a translated version of the word featured on the 'front' view, if you swipe across the front view, you don't get any crashes.

However, by the 4th time of swiping on the 'back' view it'll crash.

Here is my entire code....

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var selectedlanguage = Ti.App.Properties.getString('langSelect');

// detect height
if (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight == 480) {
    var MVTOP = 115;
    var tapTOP = 83;
    var swipeTOP = 275;
} else {
    var MVTOP = 165;
    var tapTOP = 133;
    var swipeTOP = 325;
}

var masterView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: MVTOP,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 0.7
});

var state = true;

win.add(masterView);

var front = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 1.0,
    touchEnabled: false
});


var back = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 1.0,
    touchEnabled: false
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_german,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_english,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});

var word_id_num = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_english,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});


var dropButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: 120,
    height: 41,
    right: 15,
    bottom: 15,
    title: 'drop word',
    backgroundColor: '#fd0100',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    },
    opacity: 1.0
});

// add buttons to window
win.add(dropButton);


// the main function which controls the word display
function loadWords() {

    state = true;

    // step 1. get a random pair of words (English & German)
    var db = Ti.Database.open('germanV6');
    var rows = db.execute('SELECT word_id, word_english, word_german FROM Words WHERE word_dropped = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;');

    var x = 0;
    while (rows.isValidRow()) {
        // step 2. set each label to the correct langauge (this comes from app.js when user selects their default language)
        if (selectedlanguage == 'en') {
            var word_1 = rows.fieldByName('word_english');
            var word_2 = rows.fieldByName('word_german');
        } else if (selectedlanguage == 'de') {
            var word_2 = rows.fieldByName('word_english');
            var word_1 = rows.fieldByName('word_german');
        }

        // step 3. set the word id, to be used later when wanting to 'drop' a word
        word_id_num.text = rows.fieldByName('word_id');

        rows.next();
    }

    // close database
    db.close();

    label1.text = word_1;
    front.add(label1);

    masterView.add(front);

    label2.text = word_2;
    back.add(label2);
}

// fire the function and load our words into play
loadWords();


// labels for on screen prompts
var tapLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 200,
    top: tapTOP,
    text: 'tap to flip',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    }
});

var swipeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 320,
    top: swipeTOP,
    text: 'swipe for next word',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    }
});

// add to the window
win.add(tapLabel);
win.add(swipeLabel);

var grammarButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: 120,
    height: 41,
    left: 15,
    bottom: 15,
    title: 'verb tables',
    backgroundColor: '#ffff01',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    },
    opacity: 1.0
});

win.add(grammarButton);


masterView.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    switch (state) {
    case true:
        //Ti.API.info('true');
        masterView.animate({
            view: back,
            transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT
        });
        break;
    case false:
        //Ti.API.info('false');
        masterView.animate({
            view: front,
            transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT
        });
        break;
    }
    state = !state;
});



// event listener for when the user taps the 'drop word' button
dropButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    // step 1. update the DB to tell it the word has been dropped
    var dbDelete = Ti.Database.open('germanV6');
    var rowsDelete = dbDelete.execute('UPDATE Words SET word_dropped=1 WHERE word_id=' + word_id_num.text);

    // step 2. pop up an alert to notify the user the word has been dropped
    var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title: 'Word Dropped',
        message: 'This word has been dropped!',
        buttonNames: ['OK']
    });
    // show the message
    alertDialog.show();

    // step 3. when user taps the OK button in the alert, we load in a new word by calling the loadwords() function again
    alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function (j) {
        loadWords();
    });
});

// action for when label is swiped
swipeLabel.addEventListener('swipe', function (e) {
    // reload the new word
    loadWords();
});

// action for when view is swiped
masterView.addEventListener('swipe', function (e) {
    // reload the new word
    loadWords();   
});
```

Anyone know what might be causing the crash?
Simon

Comment: You added the database close code, but removed the rows close code you use to have.  You should still have that as well.  Are you able to put together a 1 file version of this without using the database?  Something that always says front on the first word and back on the 'translation'.  I'll try running it and seeing if I see a reason that it crashes.

Comment: Your loadWords() method adds label1 and label2 to the front and back views every time that you call it (in your click and swipe event listeners, and explicitly on first run). Try adding them only once.